# Why isn't this function stopping its parent?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm created a function that stops its parent if a condition is given:

```
handleUserSubmit () {
  this.userForm.options.hasFormSubmitted = true
  if (!this.userForm.options.isFormValid) return
},

handleUpdateUser () {
  const fields = this.userForm.schema
  this.userInput.buildId = this.user.objectId
  this.handleUserSubmit()
  // rest of code
}
```

However the rest of the code runs no matter what the condition is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return` will just break out of that function - not from your overall function. Just return a boolean and then do `if (this.handleUserSubmit()) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditional return to the function from which you need to return from:

```
handleUserSubmit () {
  this.userForm.options.hasFormSubmitted = true
  return !this.userForm.options.isFormValid;
},

handleUpdateUser () {
  const fields = this.userForm.schema
  this.userInput.buildId = this.user.objectId
  if(this.handleUserSubmit()) return;
  // rest of code
}
```